# CONFUSING FORMULA - Formula Error

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a very seriously weird problems with Excel formula. Refer the following formula:

[image]

```
=INDEX(C7:D9, MATCH(H2, B7:B9, 0), MATCH(H3, C6:D6, 0))
```

Please assume the H2 and H3 is linked from some other formula which yield the value from B7:B9 and C6:D6 respectively. My problem is that the result is `#N/A` instead of returning value from the INDEX ARRAY.

Comment: You expected output is not clear. Can you explain actually what you want. Also mention h2 and h3 value.

Comment: You REALLY need to provide the returning values from the formula(s) in H2:H3. Additionally, does `=MATCH(H2, B7:B9, 0)` (put it anywhere) return a number? Does `=MATCH(H3, C6:D6, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that we don't know what `H2:H3` returns
Taking your formula:

```
=INDEX(C7:D9, MATCH(H2, B7:B9, 0), MATCH(H3, C6:D6, 0))
```

H2 needs an output like `Below 42°`!
if there is only a number like `53` replace `MATCH(H2, B7:B9, 0)` with something like `1+(H2>=42)+(H2>58)`. However, if you got `53°` you also need to replace `H2` with something like `NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(H2,LEN(H2)-1))`

Same goes for `H3`: You need to get a return like `"< 25"`. Asuming you only get a number, you need to replace `MATCH(H3, C6:D6, 0)` with something like `1+(H3>=25)`.

At least, it's not clear if thats the real problem. We really need to know the return values from `H2` and `H3`.

Answer (score 0):

You get `#N/A` because the `MATCH`-function fails. I'm almost certain it fails because the content of H2 is not type compatible with the contents in B7:B9 (or H3 not compatible with C6:D6).

Since you have string-type in B7:B9, H2 must also be string-type and the string must identically match one of the strings in B7:B9. If it matches none of them it throws `#N/A`.

> If MATCH is unsuccessful in finding a match, it returns the #N/A error
>   value.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

If there is a type-mismatch, the function will automatically fail unless Excel can cast it to the right type on the fly (and understands that it is supposed to do that), because failure to complete the comparison naturally defaults to "no match" ~~> `#N/A`.

Examine the datatypes you are comparing and fix the discrepancies, and your formula will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for being unclear in my post. Well I finally fixed the problem by replacing "1" instead of "0" on my MATCH functions. I don't know why but it fixes the #N/A error.